# Could not load NIB iOs

Tags: ios, storyboard

That is the error displayed in the console, **only** if I build my app in a real device.

2015-02-21 16:56:50.997 HiStatus[164:60b] NSMainNibFile and UIMainStoryboardFile are both set. NSMainNibFile ignored.

```
2015-02-21 16:56:53.064 HiStatus[164:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/2C26B1F0-B064-49DF-85E3-AEEE404E8A38/Example.app> (loaded)' with name 'zx4-Jk-sTp-view-OsP-Nr-lO4' and directory 'Main.storyboardc''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x307bcfd3 0x3b035ccf 0x307bcf15 0x33347d75 0x332a062b 0x330fcbed 0x32fdd30d 0x32fdd289 0x33086937 0x330c34b3 0x330c1deb 0x330c0e55 0x13ec8c 0x13ed4c 0x3119c163 0x307881b7 0x30787dcf 0x3078616b 0x306f0f0f 0x306f0cf3 0x35649663 0x3303c16d 0x13b7bc 0x13b8d8 0x3b542ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

After a Xcode restart it have add to the console that error:

```
2015-02-21 17:11:51.839 HiStatus[183:60b] NSMainNibFile and UIMainStoryboardFile are both set. NSMainNibFile ignored.

/private/var/mobile/Applications/5C841D54-3A68-40F7-BA87-32CBE8EDAF78/Library/Caches/Federico-Malagoni.HiStatus/Cache.db-wal: Too many open files
/private/var/mobile/Applications/5C841D54-3A68-40F7-BA87-32CBE8EDAF78/Library/Caches//Cache.db-journal: Too many open files
/private/var/mobile/Applications/5C841D54-3A68-40F7-BA87-32CBE8EDAF78/Library/Caches//Cache.db-shm: Too many open files
2015-02-21 17:11:53.866 HiStatus[183:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Could not load NIB in bundle: 'NSBundle </var/mobile/Applications/5C841D54-3A68-40F7-BA87-32CBE8EDAF78/HiStatus.app> (loaded)' with name 'zx4-Jk-sTp-view-OsP-Nr-lO4' and directory 'Main.storyboardc''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x307bcfd3 0x3b035ccf 0x307bcf15 0x33347d75 0x332a062b 0x330fcbed 0x32fdd30d 0x32fdd289 0x33086937 0x330c34b3 0x330c1deb 0x330c0e55 0x16dc8c 0x16dd4c 0x3119c163 0x307881b7 0x30787dcf 0x3078616b 0x306f0f0f 0x306f0cf3 0x35649663 0x3303c16d 0x16a7bc 0x16a8d8 0x3b542ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Info
[image]
Info.plist
[image]

After Edit 2 that is the error :

```
2015-02-21 17:33:07.820 HiStatus[196:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'There doesn't seem to be a valid compiled storyboard at path '/var/mobile/Applications/10C6A1F4-BAE9-4317-8CEA-CB419235A62C/HiStatus.app/Main.storyboardc''
*** First throw call stack:
(0x307bcfd3 0x3b035ccf 0x334aaa71 0x18545c 0x180880 0x180d4c 0x3119c163 0x307881b7 0x30787dcf 0x3078616b 0x306f0f0f 0x306f0cf3 0x35649663 0x3303c16d 0x17d7bc 0x17d8d8 0x3b542ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: show me your copy bundle resources and also try again a clean

Comment: There is no red file.. After clean same problem. But, I can't understand why it working on simulator and it doesn't working in real device.. @dehlen

Answer (score 0):

Did you try performing `Clean` on your project and removing an app from device?

1. Delete an app from your device
2. Perform `Clean` ( `Cmd + Shift + K` by default)
3. Install it again

Answer (score 0):

Some code or screenshot would help but make sure you do not have a typo in it. Maybe you renamed some files which are marked as red now ?

**EDIT**: 
Your plist looks broken to me. You should remove the entry "Main Nib file..." since you are already specifying a main storyboard in there.

Also the name in the error message is really weird: `zx4-Jk-sTp-view-OsP-Nr-lO4`.

Maybe a screenshot of your project setup and the code how you try to load the nib could solve the puzzle.

**EDIT 2**
Ok try these steps:

- Locate LauncScreen.xib on your disk
- Remove the red LaunchScreen.xib from your project and re-add the file to your project
- In Targets -> Build Phases Make sure all .xib files are added to Copy Bundle Resources, if not add them
- Remove "Main Nib file ..." from your .plist

Comment: Only LaunchScreen.xib are red.